# Authentic Dua for increasing memory

Tags: sunnah, dua, quran-memorization

Is there any authentically reported `Hadith` or `Quran` ayat for Supplication to enhance memory?

Comment: As phrased, this seems likely to just attract lists of items rather than a comprehensive answer: What counts as "authentic"?  What would make any supplication better or worse than any other?  Please note that the Stack Exchange model is geared towards practical answerable questions, but many questions are just not suitable for this format; see the help centre page on "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" for an idea of the sorts of questions we prefer to handle here.

Comment: Have you already tried nutrition for that purpose?

Comment: @infatuated yes, but general nutrition, not specific for memory.

Answer (score 3):

Dr. Zakir Naik, a renowned dynamic international orator on Islam and Comparative Religion, when asked about this question, he gave this answer. “I recite this dua for improving my memory” Surah Taha, verse 25-28
[image] 

There are other ayah's as well in Quran, which can be treated as dua as well to enhance memory.

[image]

Comment: Did he refer any hadith? From the Prophet salallahualayhiwassalam or any Sahaba did the same thing?

Comment: No, he didn't refer any hadith.. but we can see the translation of these Ayahs of quran, which clearly depicting that these are duas to enhance memory